# Cisco ISDN WAN - what exactly is it?

Tags: networking, router, wan, expansion-cards

I'l looking to get into Cisco router configuration, and I think I have found an appropriate router to buy, however its a Cisco 1841 and therefore has two Fast Ethernet and two expansion slots, no WAN port.

Is a Cisco WIC-1B-S/T ISDN WAN Interface Card a special card, or does it just add an Ethernet port identical to the WAN port of many consumer routers like an Apple Airport or a Netgear WAN router?

Comment: Are you considering this WIC because it was listed for sale and extremely cheap? ISDN is an antiquated precursor to DSL, it's still around but expensive service and typically topped out at 128kbs, that's slow.
Telecom companies will happily sell it you if you like https://www.att.com/gen/general?pid=9448
 but for the 1841, I'd shop for an Ethernet WIC's if you're hungry for more Ethernet ports:

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/routers/2800-series-integrated-services-routers-isr/product_data_sheet0900aecd80581fe6.html

Comment: @UncertainWhatNameToPickHere I'm not looking for ethernet ports, rather a single WAN port such as the one found of standard routers these days. AT leats I know this ISDN is not what i'm looking for.

Comment: WHELP, that IS a WAN port on these HWIC's that you're describing as a standard router, you can also use one of your existing Fast Ethernet Interfaces (FA0/0 or FA0/1) as a "standard WAN port" on a router w/o buying an HWIC.
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/routers/2800-series-integrated-services-routers-isr/product_data_sheet0900aecd80581fe6.html

HWIC's are commonly used as other than Ethernet adapters like Serial PPP or that bargain ISDN card you considered.

Comment: @UncertainWhatNameToPickHere oh I see now! So ANY Ethernet port can be configured as a WAN port on a Cisco router right? Could you also condense your comments into an answer so I can mark it as solved and give you credit? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Ethernet ports are WAN ports if you configure the router correctly.

An Apple Airport / Netgear WAN port is also a NAT port like FA0/0 or FA0/1 could be.

The [WIC cards found at](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/routers/2800-series-integrated-services-routers-isr/product_data_sheet0900aecd80581fe6.html) at this Cisco page provide additional Ethernet ports to NAT multiple subnets in your office to an exterior network.

[image]

HWIC's are commonly used as other than Ethernet adapters like Serial PPP or the bargain ISDN card you considered.